# Google cloud: How to set up VM and spin off instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am new to google cloud and want to make sure I start off correctly - so apologies for the naive questions! I have been trying to look up the documentation, but it seems a bit over-whelming at the moment!

With SGE, I store my data on a drive, install software in my local directory and spin off cores/cpus with the gsub command. In gcloud, so far I have:

1. Stored my data in a bucket.
2. Created a VM and install software on this

My questions:

1. How do I save the VM image so that I don’t have to install the software for each new instance of VM?
2. How/what script do I write to spin off 10 VMs(?) so that each VM gets a different chunk of the data I have in my bucket?

Or am I thinking of this incorrectly? Should I be approaching this differently? Any specific documentation pages that would help me?

Sorry, completely new to the cloud and want to make sure I do things correctly.

thanks for all help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a managed instance group. A managed instance group contains identical VMs. In order to create a  managed instance group you have to create an Instance Template and then use it to create VMs for you group. See [Creating Instance Templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates) for more information